# row deletion in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a table say `incompatible` which has two columns namely `codeA` and `codeB`. Now, I have two entries as `A, B` and `B, A` if A is incompatible to B. My question is how do I remove one of the rows from the table in mysql?

Comment: It would be better if you explain with a proper data set and expected results.

Comment: okay. Say I have a table which has two subject codes and the table has values say (A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, A), etc. Now how do I remove the (B, A) if (A, B) is already present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM incompatible AS t1
INNER JOIN incompatible AS t2 ON t1.codeA = t2.codeB AND t2.codeB = t1.codeA 
WHERE t1.codeA > t1.codeB
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2e6/1)